# Expression result unused in label text

Tags: ios7, xcode5

j is int variable, _option1 is NSString

```
 quest.text = (@"%d %@",j, _optoin1);
```

Warning : Expression result unused for UILabel - quest.text
any can give me definition

Comment: quest.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d %@",j, _optoin1];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use NSString StringWithFormat as

```
 quest.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"\%d. %@ ",j,_optoin1];
```